# Checking if the latest record is older than 1 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've recently made a small application, that sends an e-mail.
I'm currently trying to have it send an e-mail whenever the latest record in an SSMS database, is older than 1 hour.

I'm using a case statement in the SQL query, to try and have the query return 1 or 0.

How would I make the SQL Query?

I'd hoped for an input like:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    ELSE result
END;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; SQL Server does not suppose `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: @Larnu yes it does.

Comment: No, it doesn't, @JeffUK . T-SQL has never supported `Case` **statements**, only expressions.

Comment: Right, in that case "That construct is a case expression not a case statement" would have been a (marginally) more useful comment.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Case expression?  Why not just count all records that are less than an hour old, and if you get `0` back from SQL do something?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just add a WHERE clause to find the records that match your condition? `...where DATEDIFF(hour, startdate, enddate) > 1`

Comment: Let's break this down. Your application simply needs to determine if <your condition> is true. So if your query returns a row (regardless of the content of the row), then you can make that decision. So - how would you write a query to do that? Maybe something like `select 1 from dbo.tableofinterest where <somedatetimecolumns> < dateadd(hour, -1, getdate());` If that query returns any row, then you send an email. You might need to aggregate to find "latest" - it's not clear what your table contains

Answer (score 1):

You can have a select statement, which checks if any record is found then return 1, else 0.

```sql
SELECT CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE datediff(hh,datecolumn,getdate())>1) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AS NewRecordsFound
```

Or

```sql
SELECT IIF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE datediff(hh,datecolumn,getdate())>1),1,0) AS NewRecordsFound
```

Or

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE datediff(hh,datecolumn,getdate())>1)
BEGIN
SELECT 1 AS NewRecordsFound
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 0 AS NewRecordsFound
END
```